# How to organize a list of tags with IDs and subtag-relations into a nested structure?

Tags: matlab, data-structures

I have a given 1xN-fields struct array nested with N structs with three fields:

- `id`: unique numerical identifier
- `name`: unique alphanumeric name
- `parent_id`: parental relation to another `id`

The parental relation is given by `parent_id`, which refers to another `id` under which this current ID is nesting, making the current tag a subtag. The `parent_id` can also be blank, meaning that the current ID is at root level and not nested under any other ID. Example:

```
tags = 
    field1: [1x1 struct]
    field2: [1x1 struct]

tags.field1 = 
           id: 1
         name: 'tag1'
    parent_id: []


tags.field2 = 
           id: 2
         name: 'tag2'
    parent_id: 1
```

With a struct like `tags` from above, `field2` would be nested in `field1` in a tree diagram. Which leads me to the problem: How can I reorganize data in the given format efficiently to generate text based tree diagrams and provide the data for further processing?

One approach I tried was the reorganization into a whole bunch of nested structs, like this:

```
tags_sorted = 
    field1: [1x1 struct]

tags_sorted.id_1 = 
           id: 1
         name: 'tag1'
    parent_id: []
         id_2: [1x1 struct]

tags_sorted.id_1.id_2 = 
           id: 2
         name: 'tag2'
    parent_id: 1
```

Leading to deeper and deeper nestings as the number of subtags of subtags (of subtags, of subbtags …) rises. I could not come up with an algorithm that is capable of handling an unlimited number of nestings.

Any ideas for that? I'm afraid the input data structure of `tags` can not be altered.

Comment: Maybe [this contribution on the File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35623-tree-data-structure-as-a-matlab-class) is of interest to you.

Comment: Yep, I know the tree class. A fine piece of software, but unable to eradicate my problem of structuring the data before further processing/displaying.